# How to have dynamic values on key's state from a reducer, based on another value which is store in another reducer ? React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to modify the attack key of this object, which is in "monsterReducer.js" (combinedReducers)

```
{
   name: 'BroodLord',
   portrait: '"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7f/1d/b5/7f1db5d78fb1964b7dfd92569b92bd74.jpg"',
   text: "No special rules",
   level: 5,
   experience: 20,
   treasure: 1,
   strengh: 10,
   defense: 11,
   gold: 8,
   monsterType: 'normal',
},
```

... based on another value who might be on another reducer (generalReducer.js), with a formula like :

```
{
    attack : Math.floor(Math.random() * X + Y
},
```

...where X & Y are variable from other reducer, has said above. I also face the problem that the reducers seems to be read only one time by the machine, hence i dont see how it could be dynamic here.

Comment: You can send X and Y as payloads when you are dispatching the action. Since they are in other reducers you can add them to your props using `mapStateToProps` and then use them in your component.

Comment: Official doc explains all the options: https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers/#how-do-i-share-state-between-two-reducers-do-i-have-to-use-combinereducers

Comment: Also it is worth noting that reducers must be pure functions. It means you can't have `random` in reducer itself. Side effects (like getting a random number) belong to action creators and/or middlewares.